# Mapping Contact record to Identity while using IdentityServer4

Tags: authentication, .net-core, identityserver4

**Scenario:** A customer database where every customer can have many contacts and all these contacts need individual login credentials to sign in to a portal. The contacts will have many personal contact information such as name, dob, address, contact numbers, etc..

Using IdentityServer4 I created all that is necessary for a user to authenticate together with the database objects for every IdentityUser, in this case the AspNetUsers table.

*Now i'm wondering what would be the way to link the AspNetUsers table to the Contacts table that define the Contact entity.*

Considering that the AspNetUsers table already contains email address and phone, should I make the Contact Entity to extend from the IdentityUser and use Contact with IdentityServer4 or should I link the entities via some FK?

Comment: Are you using .Net Core 1.x or 2.x?

Comment: Hi @aaronR, I'm using .net core 2

Comment: Do you need the linking of the customer to contact for authentication?

Comment: What i'm looking for is to see how to link a Contact (which represents a user of a web portal) to the Identity object that is authenticated, given that every Contact will have an Identity.

Comment: so essentially, when someone logs in, from the Identity i need to get to the Contact.

Comment: You mean something like `services.AddIdentityServer() .AddAspNetIdentity<ApplicationUser>();`? https://identityserver4.readthedocs.io/en/release/quickstarts/6_aspnet_identity.html#configure-identityserver

Comment: Hi @cheesemacfly, yes, i'm looking for a recommendation. What they did with ApplicationUser, can that be my business object 'Contact' knowing that my object has properties that does not strictly have to do with authentication?

Comment: @skyplusplus yes you could (even tho you might be breaking separation of concern if you mix authentication and authorization). Take a look at what the extension method is doing: https://github.com/IdentityServer/IdentityServer4.AspNetIdentity/blob/release/src/IdentityServer4.AspNetIdentity/IdentityServerBuilderExtensions.cs#L28 Best think to do I guess is to give it a shot.